# How do I convert a MultipartFile to a FileSystemResource

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to convert MultipartFile to a FileSystemResource?

I have

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
```

and then

```
prmPowerPoint.setFileSystemResource(fileSystemResource); // which accepts FileSystemResource
```

I want to convert `file` to `fileSystemResource` but I have no idea what path should I follow.

Comment: What is your strategy for handling the (temporary) uploaded file - do you have a target folder where to store it or do you want to process it in memory?

Comment: @Smutje, I would prefer to process it in memory.

Comment: Of what class is `prmPowerPoint`? Please provide a complete example of what you are planning to do with the uploaded file so that others can help and don't need to speculate.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you save the file first

```
    File f = new File("/tmp/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
    file.transferTo(f);

    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(f);
```